# Where does edit button go in Magento?

Tags: shopping-cart, router, edit

In my shopping cart there is an edit button for each product!
I would like to know how do I get to that phtml page for edit?
I don't seem to see an edit.phtml or such

I'm passing in a parameter from the shopping cart and would like to see if it got there okay :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On clicking edit in shopping cart page it's showing the product's view.phtml file the only difference is instead of showing 'Add to cart' (frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml) it's displaying 'Update Cart'(frontend\rwd\default\template\checkout/cart/item/configure/updatecart.phtml).
So you can pass the passed parameter from the cart could be fetched in updatecart.phtml.

If you explain the question clearly like what parameter you need to fetch in the edit page, I could work and see.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the quick response. In the cart I have it so each item has an areasJson which is a huge string.  If possible I don't want to send it through the URL as its very long! Within the cart each individual item has an $areasJson associated with it that is a php variable. If possible could I stuff the long string into an object / array and pass that through the url? Or could you explain how I could do it through a controller?

Comment: I'll be sure to upvote your answer if it works too thanks for taking the time to help me ^_^

Comment: Hi!
My idea is better to assign the $arrayjson into an input hidden field and fetch the value where you need.

Comment: I can place that hidden field in the cart? and it will show up in the edit page? This sounds like it could work! What's confusing to me though is that the edit page doesn't share the same <divs>

Comment: If I saved the info to a hidden input field in the Cart, how would I access that exact input in the edit page?

Comment: On clicking each product edit , that particular product edit page is displaying so I guess if you place the hidden field with that logic it will work

Comment: Hey , I think in the cart you keep the input hidden field inside the form with the submit button.
On clicking the edit link, us js to click that submit button.
Then fetch that Form details in the product edit page.

Comment: Make sure to dynamically update the $arrayjson inside the form for each products